# Interpreting bits in union fields as different datatypes in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, unions

I am trying to access Union bits as different datatypes. For example:

```
    typedef union {
    uint64_t x;
    uint32_t y[2];
    }test;

    test testdata;
    testdata.x = 0xa;
    printf("uint64_t: %016lx\nuint32_t: %08x %08x\n",testdata.x,testdata.y[0],testdata.y[1]);
    printf("Addresses:\nuint64_t: %016lx\nuint32_t: %p %p\n",&testdata.x,&testdata.y[0],&testdata.y[1]);
```

The output is

```
uint64_t: 000000000000000a
uint32_t: 0000000a 00000000
Addresses:
uint64_t: 00007ffe09d594e0
uint32_t: 0x7ffe09d594e0 0x7ffe09d594e4
```

The starting address pointed to by `y` is same as starting address of `x`. Since both fields use the same location, shouldn't the values of `x` be `00000000 0000000a` ?

Why this is not happening? How can the internal conversion happen in  a Union with different fields of different datatypes?

What needs to be done to retrieve the exact raw bits as uint32_t in the same order as in uint64_t using a union?

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, C++ gives undefined behaviour.
How does it work in C? Can we actually do it?

Answer (score 6):

I will first explain what happens in your implementation.

You are doing *type punning* between an `uint64_t` value and an array of 2 `uint32_t` values. According to the result, your system is little endian and gladly accepts that type punning by simply re-interpreting the byte representations. And the byte representation of `0x0a` as a little endian `uint64_t` is:

```
Byte number  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7  
Value        0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

The least significant byte in little endian has the lowest address. It is now evident why the `uint32_t[2]` representation is `{ 0x0a, 0x00 }`.

But what you are doing is only legal in C language.

#### C language:

C11 says as 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members:

> 3 A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier designates a member of
>   a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,<sup>95)</sup> and is an lvalue if
>   the first expression is an lvalue.

The <sup>95)</sup> note says explicitly:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value in the object, **the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type** as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
>   punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

So even if notes are not normative, their intent is to make clear the way the standard should be interpreted => you code is valid and has defined behaviour on a little endian system defining `uint64_t` and `uint32_t` types.

#### C++ language:

C++ is more strict in that part. Draft n4659 for C++17 says in [basic.lval]:

> 8 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined:<sup>56</sup>
>   (8.1) — the dynamic type of the object,
>   (8.2) — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (8.3) — a type similar (as defined in 7.5) to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (8.4) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (8.5) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>   (8.6) — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic
>   data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>   contained union),
>   (8.7) — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (8.8) — a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

And the note <sup>56</sup> says explictely:

> The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

As *punning* is never referenced in C++ standard and as the struct/union part does not contain the equivalent of the *re-interpretation* of C, that means that reading in C++ the value of a member that is not the one that was last written invokes undefined behaviour.

---

Of course common compiler implementation compile both C and C++, and most of them accept the C idiom even in C++ source, for the very same reason that gcc C++ compiler gladly accepts VLA in C++ source files. After all, *undefined behaviour* includes expected results... But you should not rely on that for portable code.

Comment: Notably, this is one reason why C++ is unsuitable for hardware-related programming, where you often have to type pun through union either between different integer types (example: 32 bit register but CPU is 16 bit) or between some type and the byte type `uint8_t` (when doing any form of serialization/de-serialization). Not only does this make C++ incredibly cumbersome for hardware-related programming; this also causes C++ to invoke nasty UB bugs when you grab a hardware register map written from C.

Comment: I strongly disagree. In practice, this works on all sane compilers. C++ is the only language except C that is suitable for kernel work and hard real-time systems. And you get better, 0-cost abstractions and RAII built into the language.

Comment: Since we are reading it as uint32_t, according to the endianness it will read 4 bytes not 2 bytes per read from LSB to MSB from 'uint64_t' right?

Comment: @Lundin: The C Standard makes no attempt to describe when, if ever, an access via pointer or lvalue which is derived from one of another type should be recognized as an access via the original, but instead treats that as a Quality of Implementation issue.  The authors acceptance of "conforming" implementations of such poor quality to be useless [described in the rationale] meant that the Standard not only makes no effort to exhaustively describe cases where compilers should recognize such derived lvalues--it doesn't even define obvious cases like `someAggregate.member`.

Comment: Consequently, it's possible to have quality C implementations that are suitable for embedded or systems programming, and it's also possible to have obtusely-designed but "conforming" implementations that aren't suitable for such purposes, or even any purpose whatsoever.  If someone is making a bona fide effort to produce a high-quality implementation that is maximally suitable for embedded or systems programming on a platform, the Standard and platform specs together would likely give them all the information they need, but only if they refrain from doing things contrary to that purpose.